# actxserver in SciLab

Tags: com, scilab

I am trying to run a program through SciLab using actxserver command ( similar to MATLAB). But it is showing error.

I have used the same command in MATLAB and it works.
The command is

> > DC= actxserver('DesktopController.CoModel');

It gave error: Undefined variable: actxserver

Please use the ProgID that you have to try on your PC.

Thanks

I am using : SciLab 6.0.0 for windows 7 64 Bit
https://www.scilab.org/en/download/latest

Comment: You need to improve your post: please provide the exact comment you ran in Scilab with the corresponding output from the console. We can't guess the error you had.

Comment: Thank you. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `actxserver` isn't proved by standalone Scilab : you will need an external toolbox and install-it locally, you can find it at http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/ole/

## Installing the `OLE` toolbox

### Requirements

- Scilab between 5.4.0 and 5.5.2 (doesn't work with Scilab 6.0.0 natively)
- Windows

### How to

1. Clone the git project at url git://git.forge.scilab.org/ole.git ([direct download](http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/ole/source/download/master/))
2. Launch Scilab 5.X.Y with X >= 4

#### Under scilab

```
exec('builder.sce',-1)
exec('loader.sce',-1)
// now example at http://forge.scilab.org/index.php/p/ole/ should be available
```

## Making it works with Scilab 6.0.0

Change file `builder.sce` line 15 and `loader.sce` line 12 to :

```
if and([v(1)<5,v(2)<4]) then
```

this should let the toolbox start on scilab 6.0.0

Comment: Do I need visual studio to build?
I tried with VS 2016 but the code did not compile and gave some errors. Is there any other way?

Comment: No, you don't. Just download the directory and run builder.sce then loader.sce. WARNING: you need scilab 5.4.0 or 5.5.1 but not 6.0.0. This is an old package.